# Texture painting mode not responding in the 3d view

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I followed numerous tutorials, but no matter how much I click in the 3d view, the texture does not change. I made a new image, unwrapped it, and added a new texture node.

This is the video I watched
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcCQKuWPhXk&t=116s

Comment: The issue seemed to be suddenly resolved. I just exited my last session and opened it up with a gray image instead of a black one.

Comment: Post a screen shot or a summary of what you did to fix it as an answer for others that look for a similar situation.